# ADT Plugin in Eclipse not shown

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just installed the Android Developer Tools for Eclipse and restarted the programm. After that I am supposed to configure the plugin under Window > Preferences > Android, but there are NO signs of any Android Plugin anywhere. The Plugin is just invisible, altough it is marked as installed.

I installed the ADT-Plugin on two other computers some time before. Never encountered that problem.

Comment: This may answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691009/eclipse-indigo-android-adt-install-ok-no-android-option-in-preferences-and/9542700#9542700

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the Java setup on your machine.  That was the problem.  I wasted some half a day.