# Eclipse Indigo Android ADT - install OK, no "Android" option in Preferences and New Project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-indigo

I have Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149) running on Win XP.

I've added 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
and installed 4 plugins, including ADT, and restarted Eclipse.
Installed software list shows Android plugins are installed.

But nothing appears in Preferences, and there are no Android-type project in New Projects.

Later I check Eclipse's directories and there were four *.jar archives with these Android plugins, and they weren't unzipped to corresponding directories (like other plugins). I unpacked them so directories same as *.jar names, and started Eclipse again, but nothing happens.

How can I work with ADT plugin in Eclipse?

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same problem on windows 7 running Indigo. I eventually discovered that I had accidentally not run Eclipse as an administrator when I installed the ADT plugin. I solved the issue by uninstalling the ADT plugin, and then re-installing the ADT plugin when running Eclipse as an administrator. Once I did that Eclipse restarted and immediately prompted me for the location of my android SDK.

As far as steps go:

1. Run Eclipse as Administrator
2. Go to Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details
3. Select Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer, and Android Traceview
4. Click Uninstall and click through the dialogs
5. Restart Eclipse at the prompt
6. Close Eclipse and re-run it as an administrator (not sure if this was necessary but I wanted be sure Eclipse had full permissions when I reinstalled the ADT Plugin)
7. Re-install the ADT plugin the way you did before.
8. Restart Eclipse at the prompt.

Comment: Didn't work at all and took lot's of time to process all the steps.

Comment: @MohammedArif sorry to hear that. This seems to work for many people but it does seem like this issue can have multiple causes (they all seem to be permission or path variable related though). Did you ever discover a solution, and if so, can you post or link it?

Comment: Someone Suggested these shorted steps as an edit. I haven't tried them so I can't verify if they work:

As far as steps go:

(1)Run Eclipse (as Administrator)
(2)Go to Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details
(3)Select Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer, and Android Traceview
(4)Click Update and click through the dialogs
(5)Restart Eclipse at the prompt
Then create your android project.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Did you install the Android SDK?

You need to do this *in addition* to installing a) Java, b) Eclipse and c) the Android plugins for Eclipse

Here's one (of many!) "Quick Start Guides" for setting up Android on your development PC:

http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/developer/android-sdk-install-guide/

PS:
Please don't "unpack" anything, except unzipping Eclipse itself.

You might actually wish to *delete* your install and re-install from scratch (just to make sure there isn't anything "weird" in your environment).

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick reply!

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick reply! I have Java installed (jre7 and JDK 7.0_01) and Android SDK installed. I've added PATH for Android\ and Android\android-sdk (and checked - path works ok), but nothing changed, no Andorid option in Preferences.

Comment: Tried another WinXP computer and Eclipse Helios - it worked! After installing Android plugin Elcipse asked to choose installed SDK, I point to Andorit directory, and all OK. Eclipse Indigo doesn't asked anything after installing SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Well i had this issue as well, but what i see its one componment that isnt on the google servers (at least for indigo) com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
you need download the ADT from google server [ADT 20.00](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip) and the install new software in help menu as always
In the Add Site dialog, click Archive.
Browse and select the downloaded zip file.
Enter a name for the local update site (e.g., "ADT-20.0.0.zip") in the "Name" field.
Click OK.
and done choose the ADT developer that i bet you dont have installed that should fix the problem ;)

Comment: Waooo, works like charm, thanks a lot Zen, struggling a lot from long time now it's resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and nothing worked until I made my `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` point to my JDK 6, they were pointing to the 5, then before installing the ADT plugin, make sure Eclipse is using the JDK 6 in `Preferences/Java/Installed JREs`. Of course make sure you are running/installing everything as an administrator.

Comment: Stuck on Java 5. later installed Java 7, its working now. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should install start SDK package ([download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)), after that install android packages by windows/SDK manager. After that you§ll see everything you've mentioned

Comment: Everything is installed
Java 7 SDK 
Android SDK 
Eclipse
Android Plugins from Google repository

Tried to reinstall Java, Android and plugins - doesn't work.

Comment: having the same problem now in my current machine, downloaded eclipse>installed the plugin> nothing is shown in eclipse but i checked and the plugins were there.

Comment: I am repeating: "install android packages by windows/SDK manager". Have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today, and a simple removal of the installed plugin is not helpful. My final solution is:

1. Remove the Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android TraceView and Tracer for OpenGL ES first.
2. Remove the **com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_version_info** and other adt related jar directory under eclipse_home/plugins/. It is very easy to recognize based on its version_info on its name.
3. Modify the artifact.xml under eclipse_home, remove all artifact tag related with 'adt'.
4. Reinstall Android ADT again with Admin Privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to reinstall as administrator make sure to remove the ADT Plugin from the Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites.

Also something that may help is when installing the ADT Plugin you get the option for Developer Tools which the http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html guide tells you to select, but make sure to also select NDK Plugins.

And as usual do this while running as administrator. It probably doesn't make a difference but instead of clicking restart I closed Eclipse and reopened as administrator each time it was necessary.

As far as I can tell the NDK Plugin was the only thing I did differently when I finally got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu , to make story short, I tried every advice here, nothing helped (reinstall, ADT removal- adding, run as sudo, deleting .eclipse folder etc).
The cause of problem was running eclipse updates.

So, I downloaded ADT bundle as zip - adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729
unpacked it, run eclipse inside it, used existing workplace, and it worked, 'android' option appeared in Preferences.
However, there is no longer 'eclipse' splash logo at start-up, it's now called Android Developer Tools
Build: v22.0.5-757759

Answer (score 0):

The real solution to this issue is that you **MUST** run Eclipse as an Administrator before you install.  There are a number of plugins that have this same issue.