# Configuring ADT plugin for eclipse -- no Android option in preferences

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I am installing android on my pc. The OS is windows xp sp-2.
I am using following guide : http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

After Downloading the ADT Plugin when I Configuring the ADT Plugin I open the preferences via Windows > Preferences (step 1), but there is no "Android" option on the left hand side as indicated in step (2).

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: This may be answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691009/eclipse-indigo-android-adt-install-ok-no-android-option-in-preferences-and/9542700#9542700

Answer (score 2):

I just had a problem like this, here's how I solved it in under 30 seconds.  In the upper left of you Eclipse window (below the minimize, maximize, and close buttons) right-click on your Java perspective button and select Reset from the context menu.  Ridiculously simple / frustrating, right?  Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: I have solved my problem by reinstalling eclipse.
I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit)

Here are the steps that worked for me (though I suspect step 2 is sufficient).

1) Remove the ADT.

2) Move your the .eclipse directory out of the way (rename or remove it).

3) Install the ADT

As a side note, once I did this I noticed settings for ant appeared as well.

Answer (score 2):

I only see the android buttons when in the "Java" perspective, not in the "Java EE" perspective...

Answer (score 0):

is there an android icon on the bottom-left . If there is, you have installed correctly, if not, please install again:)

Comment: I have solved my problem by reinstalling eclipse.
I hope it will help others.